# Node, Express, Passport, Credential - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I came across a problem while trying to build an access control mechanism into my application. I read a lot of answers on this site, but I can't seem to find the one that solves my problem. So I just signed up and decided to ask myself.

I'm using [Passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) and I'm implementing a local strategy. Also using [Credential](https://www.npmjs.com/package/credential) for my password hash. This is the error I get when I try to login as a user and redirect to the user after successfully logging in to the home page:

```
_http_outgoing.js:346
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\src\bootstrap\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\src\bootstrap\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
at done (C:\src\bootstrap\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:957:10)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\src\bootstrap\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\utils.js:26:13)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)
```

The files involved:

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Website of Bootstrap T-Shirts",
  "main": "bootstrap.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "bootstrap",
    "t-shirt",
    "tee shirt",
    "cloth",
    "shirt",
    "fashion"
  ],
  "author": "Kingson Chinedu Odogwu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "connect": "^3.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "credential": "^1.0.0",
    "csurf": "^1.8.3",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.14",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^2.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

### bootstrap.js

```
// load modules
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server;
var startServer;

require('./config.js')(app, server);
require('./routes.js')(app);

// custom 404 page
// this should appear AFTER all of your routes
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render('404');
});

// custom 500 page
// this should appear AFTER all of your routes
// note that even if you don't need the "next"
// function, it must be included for Express
// to recognize this as an error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).render('500');
});

// END: APP SETTINGS

startServer = function startServer() {
    server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express started in ' + app.get('env') + 
        ' mode on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + 
        '; press Ctrl-C to terminate...');
    });
};

if (require.main === module) {
    // application run directly; start app server
    startServer();
} else {
    // application imported as a module via "require": export function to create server
    module.exports = startServer;
}
```

### config.js

```
// load modules
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
const multer = require('multer');
const credential = require('credential')();
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const session = require('express-session');
const appCredentials = require('./app-credentials.js');
const dbProvider = require('./lib/db-provider.js');

dbProvider.connect(appCredentials.dbUrl);

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function destination(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, __dirname + '/public/img');
    },
    filename: function filename(req, file, callback) {
        var i = file.mimetype.toString().indexOf('/');
        var l = file.mimetype.toString().length;
        var filetype = '.' + file.mimetype.toString().substring(i + 1, l);

        callback(null, Date.now() + filetype);
    }
});

const verify = (username, password, verified) => {
    dbProvider.findSet('user_accounts', "username", username, (result) => {
        var user = result[0];

        if (!user) {
            // No unexpected error, no user, reason for failure
            return verified(null, false, {
                message: 'User not found.'
            });
        }

        credential.verify(user.hash, password, (err, isValid) => {
            if (!isValid) {
                // No unexpected error, no user, reason for failure
                return verified(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect password.'
                });
            }

            return verified(null, user);
        });
    });
};

passport.use(new localStrategy(verify));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    dbProvider.findById('user_accounts', id, (user) => {
        cb(null, user);
    });
});

module.exports = function (app, server) {
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        // create a domain for this request
        var domain = require('domain').create();

        // handle errors on this domain
        domain.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error('DOMAIN ERROR CAUGHT\n', err.stack);

            try {
                // failsafe shutdown in 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.error('Failsafe shutdown.');
                    process.exit(1);
                }, 5000);

                // disconnect from the cluster
                var worker = require('cluster').worker;

                if (worker) { worker.disconnect(); }

                // stop taking new requests
                server.close();

                try {
                    // attempt to use Express error route
                    next(err);
                } catch (err) {
                    // if Express error route failed, try plain Node response
                    console.error('Express error mechanism failed.\n', err.stack);
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
                    res.end('Server error.');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Unable to send 500 response.\n', err.stack);
            }
        });

        // add the request and response object to the domain
        domain.add(req);
        domain.add(res);
        // execute the rest of the request chain in the domain
        domain.run(next);
    });

    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(multer({ storage: storage }).single('photo'));
    app.use(require('cookie-parser')(appCredentials.cookieSecret));
    app.use(session({
        secret: appCredentials.cookieSecret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(require('csurf')({ cookie: true }));

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals._csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
        next();
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var cluster = require('cluster');

        if (cluster.isWorker) {
            console.log('Worker %d received request', cluster.worker.id);
        }

        next();
    });
};
```

### routes.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const main = require('./handlers/main.js');
const admin = require('./handlers/admin.js');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', main.index);
    app.get('/home', main.index);
    app.get('/index', main.index);
    app.get('/about', main.about);
    app.get('/contact', main.contact);
    app.get('/shop', main.shop);
    app.get('/admin/products', admin.products);
    app.get('/admin/product/:id', admin.product);
    app.post('/admin/process-product', admin.processProduct);
    app.post('/admin/delete-product', admin.deleteProduct);
    app.get('/login', admin.login);
    app.get('/register', admin.register);
    app.get('/logout', admin.logout);
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), admin.postLogin);
    app.post('/register', admin.postRegister);
};
```

### handlers/admin.js

```
// Load modules
const credential = require('credential')();
const dbProvider = require('../lib/db-provider.js');

module.exports.products = function products(req, res) {
    dbProvider.findAll('products', function (arr) {
        var newArr = [];

        arr.forEach(function (product, i) {
            newArr.push({
                index: i + 1,
                id: product._id,
                name: product.name
            });
        });

        res.render('products', { layout: 'admin', products: newArr });
    });
};

module.exports.product = function product(req, res) {
    var obj = { id: req.params.id };

    if (obj.id === 'new') {
        res.render('product', { layout: 'admin', context: obj });
    } else {
        dbProvider.findById('products', obj.id, function (result) {
            if (result !== null) {
                result.id = obj.id;
                res.render('product', { layout: 'admin', context: result });
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports.processProduct = function processProduct(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var link = req.body.link;
    var file = req.file;
    var obj = {};

    if (id === 'new' || id === null || id === undefined) {
        if (!(name === null || name === undefined)) {
            obj.name = name;    
        }

        if (!(link === null || link === undefined)) {
            obj.link = link;    
        }

        if (!(file === null || file === undefined)) {
            var imgPath = file.path.slice(file.path.lastIndexOf('\img')).replace('\\', '\/');

            obj.filepath = imgPath;
        }

        dbProvider.insertOne('products', obj, function () {
            res.redirect(303, '/admin/products');
        });
    } else {
        dbProvider.findById('products', id, function (result) {
            if (result !== null) {
                if (!(name === null || name === undefined)) {
                    result.name = name;    
                }

                if (!(link === null || link === undefined)) {
                    result.link = link;
                }

                if (!(file === null || file === undefined)) {
                    var imgPath = file.path.slice(file.path.lastIndexOf('\img')).replace('\\', '\/');

                    result.filepath = imgPath;
                }

                dbProvider.replaceOne('products', id, result, false, function () {
                    res.redirect(303, '/admin/products');
                });
            } else {
                // error: couldn't update
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports.deleteProduct = function deleteProduct(req, res) {
    var theId = req.body.theId;

    if (typeof theId === 'string') { // only one item (ie 1 id) is being deleted
         dbProvider.removeOneById('products', theId, function () {
            res.redirect(303, '/admin/products');
        });
    } else { // more than one item (ie an array of ids) are being deleted
        var i = 0;
        var end = theId.length;

        var fnAsyncLoop = function fnAsyncLoop(counter, stop, array, callback) {
            if (counter < stop) {
                dbProvider.removeOneById('products', array[counter], function () {
                    fnAsyncLoop(counter + 1, end, array, callback);
                });
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };

        fnAsyncLoop(i, end, theId, function () {
            res.redirect(303, '/admin/products');
        });
    }
};

module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
        res.render('login', { layout: null});
};

module.exports.postLogin = function postLogin(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
};

module.exports.register = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', { layout: null });
};

module.exports.postRegister = (req, res) => {
    const obj = {};

    credential.hash(req.body.password, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }

        obj.username = req.body.username;
        obj.hash = hash;

        dbProvider.insertOne('user_accounts', obj, () => {
            console.log('User created');

            res.redirect(303, '/');
        });
    });
};

module.exports.logout = (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

If it's too long, i'm sorry about that. If you need further clarification on anything here do let me know.

The question is, can anyone see what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add, as at the time the above question was posted I was on Node.js runtime v6.2.1.

Comment: This error is caused because somewhere in your pipeline you (or one of your modules) have already called res.end() either explicitly or implicitly. Try running node-inspector and setting some breakpoints to step through your code and see where that's happening.